# How to turn off the IntelliJ Spring Configuration Check for a directory?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

Since I've upgraded to Intellij IDEA 13, I've been getting a warning message at startup:

```
Spring Configuration Check
Unmapped Spring configuration files found.
Please configure/setup Spring facet for modules: ...
```

When I click on the link to determine what files are unmapped, I see that they are all underneath a `bin` directory.

[image: screen shot of warning]

Is there a way I can tell IntelliJ not to warn me about files beneath `bin`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *bin* folder should be excluded from search as it contains compilation output.

Find the *bin* folder in **project view**, right click it, go to **mark directory as**, click **excluded**.

Answer (score 21):

If you just want to disable the notifications, do this:

```
IntelliJ > Preferences > Notifications > Spring Configuration Check > No popup
```

Or in IntelliJ IDEA 14

```
IntelliJ > Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > Notifications > Spring Configuration Check > No popup
```

In IntelliJ IDEA 15, this has changed once again:

```
IntelliJ > Preferences > Editor > Inspections > Deselect Spring checkbox
```

Comment: In IntelliJ 13.1, instead of "Preferences" it's "File > Settings > Notifications > etc."

Answer (score 1):

[Cory Klein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446554/cory-klein) provide working solution, but path has been changed to

```
File -> Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) -> Appearance & Behavior -> Notifications -> Spring Configuration Check > No popup
```