# Unable to get rid of Spring Configuration Check since upgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 13

Tags: spring

I keep getting spring configuration checks at project open even though Spring facet has been configured for the specified module.

```
Spring Configuration Check
Unmapped Spring configuration files found
Please configure/setup Spring facet for modules:
flow (1 file)
```

Unlike the scenario in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351275/how-to-turn-off-the-intellij-spring-configuration-check-for-a-directory), I have verified several times that I have added the Spring facet to the "flow" module in Project/Module Properties, but the warning still comes up. Two questions: how to fix and 2) how to turn off this check altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable IntelliJ Spring configuration notifications, go to:

```
Preferences > Notifications > Spring Configuration Check > No popup
```

Comment: Correct answer. But just hiding a popup is like taking a painkiller without finding out the cause of the pain.

Comment: You answered my 2nd question and that will have to do for me for now so I'm checking as answered (thx). But I agree with Erik and I assume JetBrains has a bug they need to fix.